# How to properly assign values to objects, where their assignment throws an exception

Tags: java, object, try-catch, instantiation, null-pointer

In java, one may easily need to do something such as instantiate a BufferedWriter object. This could be done in the following fashion:

```
File outFile = new File("myTestFile.txt");

BufferedWriter w = null;
try { w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFile), "utf-8")); }
catch (FileNotFoundException|UnsupportedEncodingException e) { System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }

w.write("Test string");
w.newLine();
```

Note that w is declared before the try-catch block. This is so that it is within the proper scope to use the variable after the try-catch. It is initialized with a null pointer, otherwise an IDE like netbeans will warn that the variable may have not been assigned. HOWEVER, the IDE still complains that when you reach w.write(), w could possibly have a null value. This makes perfect sense, since the try block might fail!

Is there a more elegant and sensible way to do this, in ways which will not cause logical problems like what my IDE reminds me of above?

I realize i can wrap EVERYTHING that w does in the try block, but this is not feasible for my task. How else could i initialize w, if there is another option?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it "not feasible" to wrap everything in the try-catch block? That would be the proper way to proceed. Lacking that, you should wrap the w.write and w.newLine calls in a if (w != NULL) call.

Comment: I suggest that writing to an object that might be null is not a good idea in general.  I'm not sure it is desirable to suppress this warning as it is asking for an error should that catch block get executed!

Comment: @fishinear: the main reason for this is that there is alot of code executed between when w is initialized and when i call w.close(). I personally find that the extra indentation of my code would make it harder to read, and also it makes sense to have the catch nearest the operation which throws the exception.... otherwise you have some big block of code that says catch catch catch at the bottom and feels unattached to anything. Personal preference, i guess.

Comment: *"... if the keyword 'try' exists in a function, it should be the very first word in the function and that there should be nothing after the catch/finally blocks."* - Robert C. Martin, *Clean Code*

Comment: `new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream` thats sooo not clean at all

Comment: The new resource management syntax in Java 7 makes this a little cleaner: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html

Comment: @DNA That looks very similar to the `using ()` statement in `C#`

Comment: @DNA: reading..... :)

Comment: I guess I don't get the problem with not wanting to put everything inside of the try block. Why isn't this feasible? You can catch more than a single type of exception with a try block, and you have multiple operations that can throw multiple types of exception. Nonetheless, if Java-7 is an option, the try-with-resources is definitely the way to go. It prevents the need for that `if (w != null) w.close();` check in a `finally` block pretty much. It handles disposing of the resource automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html), if you're using Java 7.

```
try (BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter
    (new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(outFile), "utf-8"))) {
    w.write("Test string");
    w.newLine();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If your problem is the amount of code that would be inside the try block, consider factoring that code into a method.

```
try (BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter
    (new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(outFile), "utf-8"))) {
    writeEverythingINeed(w);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Alternatively, you have no option but to enclose the remaining statements inside an if.

```
BufferedWriter w = null;
try { w = ... }
catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

if (w != null) {
    w.write("Test string");
    w.newLine();
}
```

Again, the block inside the if may be refactored into a method.

Comment: Hmm, won't w.write, w.newline throw an IOException and ask for their own try catch?

Comment: @Jops Indeed, they would. But the OP doesn't show us the method's `throws` clauses, so it may as well be declared as `throws IOException`. If the method doesn't throw any exceptions, these also need to be handled.

Comment: I guess there is a trade off between proper handling and readability. @afsantos, since you offered several options, although it seems an answer as simple as i want is not available, this gets my vote. Thanks!

Comment: @Drifter64 Fine-grained error handling and readability usually don't go along, indeed. If you want both, your best bet is to refactor the inner code (the writes, and whatever else) into private methods, with each method handling a logic block of the code.

Comment: @afsantos: in other words, every time i have to try, i should have some method that does just that block, so that i can try-catch and possibly finally, without it looking messy in the end. I think this is what you're saying? Maybe i have to get used to the idea, but for now i am content with seeing netbeans complain about the possible null reference. The application is in a controlled situation where the file should always exist and be able to open.

Comment: @Drifter64 Yes, that was my suggestion. If a group of operations should happen, and be handled, together (in your example, the `write` plus the `newLine`), their try block could be put inside a private method that does just that. The resulting code looks as clean as possible, avoiding excessive identation.

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to wrap everything, because that's Java language design - otherwise (given that there is no such concept as `Exceptions`), you would have to check every call to an otherwise Exception-throwing operation if your writer is still valid, which is even less feasible.

See try-catch blocks more like a special section under watch, where bad and exceptional stuff can happen without fully breaking your application.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have no choice but to wrap below lines into a try-catch:

```
w.write("Test string");
w.newLine();
```

as they are both capable of throwing IOExceptions (you can alternatively declare a throws clause though).

In Eclipse, I don't see any reason that the IDE will complain that w can be null, as you've already explicitly initialized it.

Comment: In NetBeans, it complains that it could be null because you declare it as null, and the try block is not guaranteed to work, which means w would be null.

Comment: @Drifter64 I pasted the code in NetBeans and the warning is "The assigned value is never used." Care to share the screenshot? I find it really unusual.

Comment: Jops: this is actually very common when using the structure that i used in my above post. See http://oi58.tinypic.com/2vi03rr.jpg . :)

Comment: @Drifter64 Have you seen this bug report on NetBeans, does it relate to your problem? https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=223031

Comment: It does seem similar, but i think not exactly the same. In most examples, the people are checking for a null pointer in some fashion before doing something with the variable. I believe my warning is an intended feature, not a bug.